# How to update SAS table with specific date format

Tags: sql, date, sas

I have to update some dates in a table using SAS.  The problem is that the format of the date column that I'm trying to update is not allowing me to make the changes I need.

The dates look like this 05NOV2013:00:00:00

The sql is very easy, I just don't know how to get SAS to accept what I'm trying to update.  This is what I have:

```
proc sql;
update ods.test
set start_dt = 05NOV2013:00:00:00; /*of course this is the problem section*/
quit;
```

I've been looking at this article to try to find the format and I think the formate might be "DATEw." I'm no t really sure how to update the table even if I know the name of the format.
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000195834.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update to a constant then just use a datetime literal.

```
proc sql;
update ods.test
  set start_dt = "05NOV2013:00:00:00"dt
;
quit;
```